# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'rol_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

Hola me podrian ayudar o explicar, lo que pasa tengo mi tabla usuarios y rol y estoy mandando la foreing key de rol_id a usuarios para poder registrar un usuario con su rol correspondiente pero al momento de registrarme para poder logearme me manda el siguiente error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'rol_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values () y noce que error o que le falte agregar para que me quite ese error para el usuario estoy usando dos modelos que es el de user que es este

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
```

Y este es el modelo UserEloquent que uso para mandarlo llamar al controller y poder hacer las acciones

```
class UserEloquent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='users';

    protected $fillable=['name','email','password','rol_id'];

    public function getRol()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Rol');
    }
```

y esta es la tabla de la migracion

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('rol_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
          
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

controlador registerController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
   
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: listo eso es lo que me manda error

Comment: a lo que pasa esque lo agrego aca directamente de forma visual no dentro de la bd pero si quieres la puedo hacer

Comment: vale ya agrega la insercion a la bd

Comment: esque mira osea si esta relacionada la bd con laravel pero a lo que voy esque dentro de la interfaz al momento de hacer un registro me pide nombre correo y contraseña y al momento de guardar me manda ese error como si no lo conociera pero es porque falta implementar ahi el rol id

Comment: Muestra el contenido de tu Controller, imagino que debe ser el método `register()`

Comment: Ahí está el fallo en el create, justo después de esta línea `'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),` debes indicar la clave `rol_id` y asignale el valor que corresponde

Answer (score 1):

En la creacion de la tabla se incluye el campo `rol_id` y no lleva un indicador ->nullable() por lo que es un valor requerido. Es muy probable que no se este indicando este valor al crear el usuario.

```
$table->integer('rol_id');
```

Si este valor es opcional al momento de crear el usuario debes agregarle la opcion nullable:

```
$table->integer('rol_id')->nullable();
```

De otro modo debes buscar en que parte del codigo se esta enviando el valor de `rol_id` antes de guardar el registro.

Answer (score 0):

El problema depende más de la lógica que tienes para registrar un usuario. Los posibles escenarios son:

1. Poner en tu formulario de registro un desplegable en donde se pueda elegir el rol.
2. Asignarle un rol por defecto al usuario recién creado.

El primer escenario depende del desplegable o cualquier elemento que decidas poner.
Con lo que al final tendrías algo así:

```
return User::create([
     'name' => $data['name'],
     'email' => $data['email'],
     'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
     'role_id' => $data['role_id']
]);
```

El segundo escenario bien podría resolverse de la siguiente manera:

En tu **modelo** puedes definir valores por defecto, para que cada registro nuevo se cree con ese valor asignado. Para lograrlo debes agregar la variable `$attributes`.

```
const DEFAULT_ROLE = 1;
...

protected $attributes = [
    'role_id' => self::DEFAULT_ROLE,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores:

- El primero es que asignas como *fillable* la siguiente propiedad **`rol_id`** en el modelo equivocado pues cuando haces el create invocas al modelo **`User`** y no a **`UserEloquent`**

  ```
  class UserEloquent extends Autenticatable
  {
      protected $fillable = [
       'name',
       'email',
       'password',
       'rol_id', //esto aqui no va
      ];
  }
  ```
- El siguiente es que no le asignas ni clave y menos valor en el método **`create`** al rol_id lo cual generará que ese valor (*el del rol*) al no ser **`NULL`** indique el error que ponías en la primer imagen (*que quitaste*), tal como te dejaba en los comentarios, debes declararlo para que se almacene mas o menos así:

  ```
  'rol_id' => $data["rol"], //o cualquiera que sea el name dado en la vista
  ```
- Debes agregar en el **`fillable`** pero del modelo **`User`** a la llave foránea del rol

  ```
  class User extends Autenticatable
  {
      protected $fillable = [
       'name',
       'email',
       'password',
       'rol_id',  //este acá si va por que es el modelo usado en el create
      ];
  }
  ```

**Puntos extra**

- Los modelos de esta pregunta se parecen mucho a una previa, entonces reitero la recomendación, manejen con cuidado la creación de entidades pues no hace sentido 2 modelos que al momento parecen estar destinados a lo mismo
- En la *vista* los roles pueden estar en un combo, lo cual **indica que deben primero poblarlo con una consulta que hagan a la entidad roles**
- Cuando mandes la data al controlador, es cuando recuperas el id del rol elegido y lo almacenas con los demás datos del usuario